# Число сказуемого (ед./мн)

Tags: сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число, редактура

**Причинами** ускорения глобализации, с одной стороны, **был** научно-технический **прогресс** (средства связи, снижение стоимости международных перевозок, углубление разделения труда). С другой стороны, экономисты и политики тоже внесли свой вклад в этот процесс путем либерализации рынков и уменьшения проявлений протекционизма.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложение плохо построено. Пример  редактирования:

**С одной стороны, причиной ускорения глобализации был научно-технический прогресс. С  другой стороны...**

Или так:

**Причинами ускорения глобализации были: с одной стороны, научно-технический 
прогресс, с другой стороны, действия экономистов и политиков по  либерализации рынков и уменьшению проявлений протекционизма.**

Comment: Спасибо. И я тоже думала, что зря разделили на два предложения.

Comment: А мне по душе мой первый вариант. Неужели автор претендует на то, что он указал все причины, как следует из второго варинта (и исходный текст на это тоже намекает)?

Comment: Здесь Вы правы! Наверное, претендует)